# SQL to sum values between Sunday to Saturday for last three weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a T-SQL query to get sum of a reading from Sunday to Saturday for last three weeks and predicted value for current week. The goal is to compare the values for each week to bring up a trend.

Prediction calculation for current week is Sum of reading from last Sunday * (7/day of the week)

Example : (27 * (7/4) as today Wednesday is 4th day of the week.

The Sample data is below

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| ID | Reading | ReadingDate |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       0 | 9/19/2018   |
|  1 |      27 | 9/18/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/17/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/16/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/15/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/14/2018   |
|  1 |       7 | 9/13/2018   |
|  1 |      12 | 9/12/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/11/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 9/10/2018   |
|  1 |      17 | 9/9/2018    |
|  1 |      22 | 9/8/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 9/7/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 9/6/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 9/5/2018    |
|  1 |      24 | 9/4/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 9/3/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 9/2/2018    |
|  1 |      17 | 9/1/2018    |
|  1 |       0 | 8/31/2018   |
|  1 |      19 | 8/30/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 8/29/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 8/28/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 8/27/2018   |
|  1 |       0 | 8/26/2018   |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I want the result to be as follows.

```
+----+---------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | Current | Wk_1 | Wk_2 | wk_3 | Wk1_Trend | Wk2_Trend | Wk3_Trend |
+----+---------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |      63 |   36 |   46 |   36 | Up        | Down      | Up        |
+----+---------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

But i'm getting the following.

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| ID | Reading_crnt | Reading_wk1 | Reading_wk2 | Reading_wk3 | Wk1_Trend | Wk2_Trend | Wk3_Trend | Record_Date_wk1 | Record_Date2_wk2 | Record_Date_wk3 |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |        47.25 |          27 |         118 |           0 | Up        | Down      | Up        | 9/16/2018       | 8/29/2018        | 8/8/2018        |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

This is the Script is created, but I see that the date range is differing. Please help me fix this.

```
WITH 
TRTx AS (SELECT (SUM(t1.Reading) * (cast(7 as float)/cast(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) as float))) Reading_wkexp, t1.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Record_Date
         FROM Trend_T t1
         WHERE t1.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND (SELECT max(Record_Date) FROM Trend_T) GROUP BY t1.ID
         ),
TRT1 AS (SELECT SUM(t1.Reading) Reading_wk1, t1.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Record_Date
         FROM Trend_T t1
         WHERE t1.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND (SELECT max(Record_Date) FROM Trend_T) GROUP BY t1.ID
         ),
TRT2 AS (SELECT SUM(t2.Reading) Reading_wk2, t2.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AS Record_Date2
         FROM Trend_T t2 
            JOIN TRT1 ON TRT1.ID = t2.ID
         WHERE t2.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AND TRT1.Record_Date
         GROUP BY t2.ID, TRT1.Record_Date 
         ),
TRT3 AS (SELECT SUM(t3.Reading) Reading_wk3, t3.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), TRT2.Record_Date2) AS DATE) AS Record_Date3
         FROM Trend_T t3
            JOIN TRT2 ON TRT2.ID = t3.ID
         WHERE t3.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), TRT2.Record_Date2) AS DATE) AND dateadd(DAY, -1, TRT2.Record_Date2)
         GROUP BY t3.ID, TRT2.Record_Date2 
         )
SELECT TRT1.ID,
       Reading_wkexp Reading_crnt,
       Reading_wk1,
       Reading_wk2,
       Reading_wk3,       
       TRT1.Record_Date AS Record_Date_wk1,
       TRT2.Record_Date2 AS Record_Date2_wk2,
       TRT3.Record_Date3 AS Record_Date_wk3,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wkexp > Reading_wk1 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp < Reading_wk1 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp = Reading_wkexp THEN '-'
       END Wk1_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk1 > Reading_wk2 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk1 < Reading_wk2 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk1 = Reading_wk1 THEN '-'
       END Wk2_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk2 > Reading_wk3 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 < Reading_wk3 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 = Reading_wk3 THEN '-'
       END Wk3_Trend
FROM  TRT1 
JOIN TRT2 ON TRT1.ID = TRT2.ID
JOIN TRT3 ON TRT2.ID = TRT3.ID
JOIN TRTx ON TRT1.ID = TRTx.ID
;
```

Below is the SQL to create sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Trend_T (ID Int, Reading Float null, Record_Date Datetime)

Insert into Trend_T (ID, Reading, Record_Date )
select 1, 0, '2018-09-19' union all
select 1, 27, '2018-09-18' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-17' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-16' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-15' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-14' union all
select 1, 7, '2018-09-13' union all
select 1, 12, '2018-09-12' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-11' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-10' union all
select 1, 17, '2018-09-09' union all
select 1, 22, '2018-09-08' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-07' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-06' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-05' union all
select 1, 24, '2018-09-04' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-03' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-09-02' union all
select 1, 17, '2018-09-01' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-08-31' union all
select 1, 19, '2018-08-30' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-08-29' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-08-28' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-08-27' union all
select 1, 0, '2018-08-26' ;
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: @gopinath Tips: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. Capturing the current date, e.g. `declare @Today as Date = GetDate();` (NB: `as Date`, not `as DateTime`.), and using it throughout avoids any confusion about your intent, the time-of-day, or circumstances in which `GetDate()` returns different values.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, but it's not useful as it has only year related columns. it does not have a column with Weekday number n stuffs.

Comment: I'll he happy to create my own Date table if that can ease my effort for the intended result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I am getting your expected results. I basically saved the Start & End Dates for each week into a temp table, and then I use this while compiling the results.

```
SELECT *
INTO #Weeks
FROM (
SELECT WeekType = 0, StartDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)), GETDATE()), 101), EndDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)), GETDATE())), 101)
UNION ALL
SELECT WeekType = 1, StartDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 7, GETDATE()), 101), EndDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 7, GETDATE())), 101)
UNION ALL
SELECT WeekType = 2, StartDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 14, GETDATE()), 101), EndDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 14, GETDATE())), 101)
UNION ALL
SELECT WeekType = 3, StartDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 21, GETDATE()), 101), EndDate = CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, DATEADD(DAY, (-1) * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE() - 1)) - 21, GETDATE())), 101)
) t
GO
WITH 
TRTx AS (SELECT ((SELECT SUM(t1.Reading) FROM Trend_T t1 WHERE t1.Record_Date BETWEEN (SELECT StartDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 1) AND (SELECT EndDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 1) AND t1.ID = t0.ID )
         * (cast(7 as float)/cast(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) as float))) Reading_wkexp, 
         t0.ID 
         FROM Trend_T t0
         WHERE t0.Record_Date BETWEEN (SELECT StartDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 0) AND (SELECT EndDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 0)  
         GROUP BY t0.ID
         ),
TRT1 AS (SELECT SUM(t1.Reading) Reading_wk1, t1.ID 
         FROM Trend_T t1
         WHERE t1.Record_Date BETWEEN (SELECT StartDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 1) AND (SELECT EndDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 1) 
         GROUP BY t1.ID
         ),
TRT2 AS (SELECT SUM(t2.Reading) Reading_wk2, t2.ID 
         FROM Trend_T t2 
            JOIN TRT1 ON TRT1.ID = t2.ID
         WHERE t2.Record_Date BETWEEN (SELECT StartDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 2) AND (SELECT EndDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 2)
         GROUP BY t2.ID 
         ),
TRT3 AS (SELECT SUM(t3.Reading) Reading_wk3, t3.ID 
         FROM Trend_T t3
            JOIN TRT2 ON TRT2.ID = t3.ID
         WHERE t3.Record_Date BETWEEN (SELECT StartDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 3) AND (SELECT EndDate FROM #Weeks WHERE WeekType = 3)
         GROUP BY t3.ID 
         )
SELECT TRT1.ID,
       Reading_wkexp Reading_crnt,
       Reading_wk1,
       Reading_wk2,
       Reading_wk3,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wkexp > Reading_wk1 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp < Reading_wk1 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp = Reading_wkexp THEN '-'
       END Wk1_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk1 > Reading_wk2 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk1 < Reading_wk2 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk1 = Reading_wk1 THEN '-'
       END Wk2_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk2 > Reading_wk3 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 < Reading_wk3 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 = Reading_wk3 THEN '-'
       END Wk3_Trend
FROM  TRT1 
JOIN TRT2 ON TRT1.ID = TRT2.ID
JOIN TRT3 ON TRT2.ID = TRT3.ID
JOIN TRTx ON TRT1.ID = TRTx.ID
GO
DROP TABLE #Weeks
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I complicated the date range calculation. Gave some thoughts and simplified the date ranges to get my result. Below is my solution.

```
WITH 
TRT AS  (SELECT t.ID, t.Reading, t.RECORD_DATE 
         FROM Trend_T t
         WHERE t.RECORD_DATE = (SELECT max(RECORD_DATE) FROM Trend_T) 
         ),
TRTx AS (SELECT (SUM(tx.Reading)*(cast(7 as float)/cast(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) as float))) Reading_wkexp, tx.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Record_Date
         FROM Trend_T tx
         WHERE tx.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND (SELECT max(Record_Date) FROM Trend_T) GROUP BY tx.ID
         ),
TRT1 AS (SELECT SUM(t1.Reading) Reading_wk1, t1.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Record_Date
         FROM Trend_T t1
         WHERE t1.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) % 7) - 1), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND (SELECT max(Record_Date) FROM Trend_T) GROUP BY t1.ID
         ),
TRT2 AS (SELECT SUM(t2.Reading) Reading_wk2, t2.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,TRT1.Record_Date)  AS DATE) AS Record_Date2
         FROM Trend_T t2 
            JOIN TRT1 ON TRT1.ID = t2.ID
         WHERE t2.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-7, TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,TRT1.Record_Date)  AS DATE)
         GROUP BY t2.ID, TRT1.Record_Date 
         ),
TRT3 AS (SELECT SUM(t3.Reading) Reading_wk3, t3.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-8,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AS Record_Date3
         FROM Trend_T t3
            JOIN TRT1 ON TRT1.ID = t3.ID
         WHERE t3.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-14,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-8,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE)
         GROUP BY t3.ID, TRT1.Record_Date 
         ),
TRT4 AS (SELECT SUM(t4.Reading) Reading_wk4, t4.ID, CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-15,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) Record_Date4
         FROM Trend_T t4
            JOIN TRT1 ON TRT1.ID = t4.ID
         WHERE t4.Record_Date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-21,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-15,TRT1.Record_Date) AS DATE)
         GROUP BY t4.ID, TRT1.Record_Date 
         )
SELECT TRT1.ID,
       TRT.Reading  AS Reading_crnt,
       Reading_wk1,
       Reading_wkexp,
       Reading_wk2,
       Reading_wk3, 
       Reading_wk4,      
       Cast(Getdate() as Date) AS Record_Date_wk1,
       TRT2.Record_Date2 AS Record_Date2_wk2,
       TRT3.Record_Date3 AS Record_Date_wk3,
       TRT4.Record_Date4 AS Record_Date_wk4,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wkexp > Reading_wk2 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp < Reading_wk2 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wkexp = Reading_wk2 THEN '-'
       END Wk1_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk2 > Reading_wk3 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 < Reading_wk3 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk2 = Reading_wk3 THEN '-'
       END Wk2_Trend,
       CASE
           WHEN Reading_wk3 > Reading_wk4 THEN 'Up'
           WHEN Reading_wk3 < Reading_wk4 THEN 'Down'
           WHEN Reading_wk3 = Reading_wk4 THEN '-'
       END Wk3_Trend
FROM TRT
JOIN TRT1 ON TRT.ID = TRT1.ID
JOIN TRT2 ON TRT1.ID = TRT2.ID
JOIN TRT3 ON TRT2.ID = TRT3.ID
JOIN TRT4 on TRT4.ID = TRT3.ID
JOIN TRTx ON TRT.ID = TRTx.ID
--ORDER BY TRT1.ID
;
```